# Check the Oracle 11g R2 installation type

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

How can I check if the installation of Oracle Database is done with the Administrator Option Type?

There are four installation types while installing the Oracle 11g R2 as listed below:

1. Instant Client
2. Administrator
3. Runtime
4. Custom

How can I check to see if the installation was completed with the Administrator option?

Comment: This looks like an Oracle client install, not the Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the Oracle Client?

In that case you can review the installation logs in the Oracle Inventory directory and look for the `INSTALL_TYPE` property:

```
INFO: INFO: ---------------------------------------
INFO: INFO: Starting to setup InstallClient
INFO: INFO: Initializing setup InstallClient
INFO: INFO: Session Details :
INFO: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:  PROPERTY                                               VALUE        
INFO: ---------------------------------------------------------------------                         
[...]
INFO:  INSTALL_TYPE                                           Administrator
```